# CollectionViewCell moves when the Navigation bar hides

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I am using a collection view to display the content. The cells are paged with a depth transformer. At viewDidLoad() the navigation bar hides after a delay of two seconds and after that the navigation bar shows/hides on tap. This was working fine until i updated to xCode 9. All the previous builds which were working fine with xCode 8 are giving me the same issue now. I am sure that i have not changed anything in my code. I find this most likely to happen at app launch and after that it randomly occurs at different time points This is the snippet which i am currently using to hide the nav bar:

```
 navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
  _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(hidesBar), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

[image]

Comment: "The cells are paged with a depth transformer."  What does that mean?  "At viewDidLoad() the navigation bar hides after a delay..."  That's a bad design.

Comment: Depth transformer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD6oL.gif). I wan to hide the navigation bar 2secs after the view loads. What's the better way of doing it then ? @ElTomato

Comment: Hiding the navigation bar is simply a bad idea when the release of iPhone X is imminent.